# Get WordPress Post title as JSON to HTML TICKER

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I want to create a html news ticker that pulls the title of wordpress posts as a news ticker.
I'm using this example from [Codepen](https://codepen.io/npsantini/pen/XqxNyb)

the JavaScript currently uses an array of strings

```
var newsItem = [
  {
    "date" : "05/16/18",
    "story": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
  },
  {
    "date" : "05/13/18",
    "story": "Sed quis mauris suscipit, vehicula lacus sit amet, volutpat libero. Curabitur nec scelerisque orci."
  },
  {
    "date" : "04/28/18",
    "story": "Praesent lacinia elit ut neque ornare vestibulum ac et dolor. Cras vel urna sed elit porta fringilla eget id nulla."
  },
  {
    "date" : "04/19/18",
    "story": "Praesent bibendum odio id euismod scelerisque. In tempor, ligula nec porta egestas, magna ipsum sodales libero, sit amet ultrices lorem ex vitae justo."
  },
  {
    "date" : "04/12/18",
    "story": "This is a news story 5."
  }
];

for (i = 0; i < newsItem.length; i++) {
  $("#newsTicker p").append(
    "<span class='date'>" + newsItem[i].date + ":</span>" +
    "<span class='story'>" + newsItem[i].story + "</span>"
  );
}
```

then in the html;

```
<div id="breaking">Breaking News</div>
<div id="newsTicker"><p></p></div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>News Ticker</h1>
</div>
```

the end result is to have the JSON parsed from the URL [https://104.197.172.156/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_query=[*].{id:id,title:title.rendered}](https://104.197.172.156/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_query=%5B*%5D.%7Bid:id,title:title.rendered%7D)

AS

```
var newsItem = GetJSON(url)
{('https://104.197.172.156/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_query=[*].{id:%20id,%20title:%20title.rendered}'}

somefunction= data.title

];

for (i = 0; i < newsItem.length; i++) {
  $("#newsTicker p").append(
    "<span class='title'>" + newsItem[i].title.+ ":</span>" +
    "<span class='content'>" + newsItem[i].content+ "</span>"
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten the code slightly.

You can use the [getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) function of jQuery to fetch the JSON data from your WordPress. You have to pass the url as parameter to it and the callback.

Then I used the [each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function of jQuery to iterate through the news items. Inside it, `this` will reference the current item.

Also, I noticed that you are trying to display the `content`. So in your URL, I have passed the `content: content.rendered` as parameter, so that it will return the content also. And removed the escaped white space character, for better readability.

```
var url = 'https://104.197.172.156/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_query=[*].{id:id,title:title.rendered,content:content.rendered}';

$.getJSON( url, function(result){
    $.each(result, function(){
        $("#newsTicker p").append(
            "<span class='title'>" + this.title + ":</span>" +
            "<span class='content'>" + this.content + "</span>"
        );
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t012vxdu/

Hope you will be able to manage the displaying of news ticker part.